# "TypeError: Cannot read property "parameters" from undefined" for deployed script for Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-apps-script

i am trying to insert data into Google Spreadsheet here is my Google Apps Script Code

```
function doGet(e) { // change to doPost(e) if you are recieving POST data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById("1Avuci7UYgkBPIt6IrXgHUad9og439lnj5xtn8Z-Xl4w"));
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[2]; //read headers
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // get next row
  var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
  var col = 0;
  for (i in headers){ // loop through the headers and if a parameter name matches the header name insert the value
    if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){
      val = new Date();
    } else {
      val = e.parameter[headers[i]]; 
    }
    cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue(val);
    col++;
  }
  //http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-script/thread?tid=04d9d3d4922b8bfb&hl=en
  var app = UiApp.createApplication(); // included this part for debugging so you can see what data is coming in
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  for( p in e.parameters){
    panel.add(app.createLabel(p +" "+e.parameters[p]));
  }

  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
//http://www.google.sc/support/forum/p/apps-script/thread?tid=345591f349a25cb4&hl=en
function setUp() {
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('active', SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
}
```

i am getting this error:-

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "parameters" from undefined. (line 20, file "Code")
```

Please can you help me detecting error or Inserting data via Ajax or Jquery into Google Spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps:

1. Run your doGet(e) method from script editor, it will throw the error as 
   `TypeError: Cannot read property "parameters" from undefined` which is fine, 
   because you don't have parameters now.
2. Now deploy(Publish -> deploy as a web app) this script with a new version (select new from the dropdown), you can change **Who has access to the app** criteria if you want.
3. Hit your script (deployed URL) from the browser's address bar / Ajax with parameters.
4. Put Logger.log() statements for the debugging.

Hope that, this will resolve your issue.